# COUNT several column values within one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently trying to count several column values in MySQL. My table looks as follows:

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+
|    date    | menu_person1 | menu_person2 |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
| 2020-04-29 | Menu 1       | Menu 1       |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
...
```

I would now like to identify the amount of "Menu 1" for a specific date. So in this case, the result of the code should be "2" for the selected date.

So far, I used the following code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS menu_1_count FROM my_table WHERE date = "2020-04-29" AND (menu_person1 = "Menu 1" OR menu_person2 = "Menu 1");
```

However, this would only display 1 since both values are within the same row. Is there a way to count each column?

Comment: select menu_person1, count(*) from table group by menu_person1. This will count the occurance of a value in a column

Comment: check @Gordon Linoff answer it is correct. I have tested it on windows/mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the most efficient method is:

```
SELECT SUM(menu_person1 = 'Menu 1') + SUM(menu_person2 = 'Menu 1') AS menu_1_count
FROM my_table
WHERE date = '2020-04-29' ;
```

That said, your real problem is the data model.  It is suspicious whenever you are multiple columns storing the same data.  You should really have a table with one row per date and "menu person" -- whatever that refers to.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(IF(menu_person1 = 'Menu 1', 1, 0) + IF(menu_person2 = 'Menu 1', 1, 0))
AS menu_1_count
FROM my_table
WHERE date = '2020-04-29';
```